# How do I write a CQL query for "nodetool status" on Astra DB?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, datastax-astra

I am using Astradb and want to know specific information about my database and I am unable to write a nodetool status query in astradb

I tried running noodtool status query in CQL of astraDB but it is showing "no viable alternative at input 'nodetool' ([nodetool]...)".

Answer (score 1):

So the whole idea behind Astra DB, is to *abstract* that information away from you.  However, I'm sure you can piece some of it together by querying `system.local` and `system.peers`:

```
token@cqlsh> SELECT broadcast_address, host_id, data_center, rack, tokens FROM system.local;

 broadcast_address | host_id                              | data_center | rack  | tokens
-------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        10.16.19.2 | ac8bfed1-9440-47ab-994f-b7ef98117bcf |    us-east1 | rack0 | {'-3466893331802638996', '-7189152594095502834', '-7743619013763055482', '1393532910918095565', '1597888904347105718', '3014295866360776345', '4210538617285918185', '7954653708828547606'}

(1 rows)
token@cqlsh> SELECT peer, host_id, data_center, rack, tokens FROM system.peers;

 peer      | host_id                              | data_center | rack  | tokens
-----------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10.16.7.2 | 4e3f943d-8c53-46c6-801e-6dabca21a2e0 |    us-east1 | rack1 | {'-2359035084030801128', '-3568203120055674420', '-7527234136092159677', '2040951025520895185', '5112277637022770422', '7536877072455490670', '7596502811906969058', '8655155433379455388'}
 10.16.4.3 | 6157e7e6-fc87-4471-8436-a55791b5c687 |    us-east1 | rack2 |  {'-1573689545965570176', '-2873530414896862389', '-4711666288472706723', '-788972128988926049', '1360301076154144663', '6409534500549901780', '7611313913660737863', '977603904086666902'}

(2 rows)
```

And if you're looking for cluster Load (from nodetool status), your best bet is to check the "Storage Consumed" section on your Astra DB dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) is a **cloud-native**, **serverless**, **fully-managed** Cassandra-as-a-service. These three terms are relevant to your question because Astra DB uses a completely different model/implementation/architecture/paradigm than a traditional Cassandra cluster.

Being cloud-native and serverless, there are "no servers" involved and the concept of Cassandra nodes no longer makes sense. Instead of nodes and servers, the functions and operations performed by a traditional Cassandra node are now done by services. For example, the coordinator function is now performed by *Coordination Services* and reading/writing data is now performed by *Data Services*.

In his answer, @Aaron showed how to query the `system.peers` table. Those peers are in fact just the [Stargate](https://stargate.io/) coordinator pods which provide *Coordination Services* which coordinate read and write requests to the relevant *Data Services*. Those peers are not the same as the traditional Cassandra nodes you may be used to.

Finally, it also doesn't make sense to have the ability to run `nodetool status` on your Astra database. Since it is a fully-managed DB-as-a-service, all you should care about is whether your app can read or write from the database.

I like to use Gmail as an analogy. It is a mail-as-a-service that is fully-managed by Google. You would never contact Google to ask for the list of mail servers that are used for your mail. All you care about is whether you can send or receive email. The same idea applies to Astra DB. Cheers!